# Is this patent [US7611025] applicable in India?

Tags: design-patent

In reference to the patent: [US7611025](https://www.google.com/patents/US7611025)

Is this patent [US7611025] applicable in India? Would appreciate if anyone could guide me on how to confirm the same.

Comment: You have tagged this “design-patent” but it is a utility patent.

Answer (score 1):

No. A US patent has no protection in India unless they were manufacturing the invention for sale in the US.  The mere manufacturing of the invention is not protected but the sale of it to the US is.  The US patent only applies to US states and territories.

Comment: The can be foreign equivalents. This would be a better answer noting that and better still if you determined if there is an Indian patent.

Answer (score 1):

This application had french priority (FR 2003002061, 2002-07-12). Through WIPO it entered eight countries including US. It did not enter India in National Phase. Hence, it is not appicable in India. For confirmation search:
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2004007313&recNum=1&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=&tab=PCT+Biblio (WO2004007313);

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=en_EP&submitted=true&DB=&query=FR2003002061&Submit=Search (FR2003002061)

Answer (score 0):

Any patent applied for in India (or any country) will have a priority number. The priority number may be the application number in India, that is to say it was applied first in India or may contain another priority number from any other country, which means it was applied for in other jurisdictions before applying in India.
Along with priority number, INPADOC family ID is available through ESPACENET, which links same patents with a single ID.
If you want to know whether the mentioned patent was also applied in India, you must search for the US patent as priority number and/or its INPADOC family ID in India.